# Integral of $\frac{C}{x-C}$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I'm sure this is quite a simple question, but am I right that

$$
\int\mathrm dx\frac{C}{x-C} = C \int\mathrm dx\frac{1}{x-C} = C\,\mathrm{log}\left(|x-C|\right) + \mathrm{const.}
$$

If yes, then why does Anthony Zee get $p-q=2r+2r_S\,\,\mathrm{log}\frac{|r-r_S|}{r_S}$ on page 424 of his *Einstein Gravity in a Nutshell*? Why the $r_S$ term in the denominator inside of the logarithm?

[image]

It isn't listed in [the errata list](http://www.bradcarlile.com/physics/zee-einstein-gravity-in-a-nutshell-errata.html), and the denominator is later used to cancel an $r_S$, so I'm pretty sure it's not a typo.

Comment: You forgot something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both you and Zee are right: remember that this is indefinite integration, so you have no way to choose the integration constant; any such constant is equally good. Now, Zee's result can be rewritten as $2 r_s \log |r - r_s| - 2 r_s \log r_s$, and $2 r_s \log r_s$ is just a constant (with respect to $r$), so you may absorb it into your own $\text{const}$.

Comment: That's it, thank you!